# postfix forward certain users to exchange server

Tags: linux, postfix, forwarding

I have been googling for a couple hours trying to figure this out.  This is happening as we speak on a LIVE mail server, which I thought I had tested properly before rolling LIVE.

What we have is a Postfix server setup with IMAP/POP3, etc.  95% of my users just get delivered locally to postfix.  But what I have is 5 users, that need to be forwarded to an exchange server.

The domain is the same for all the users so I can't split by domain.

Noone can send email to these users that are on the exchange system?  I keep getting "User unknown in virtual alias table" error messages.

I set up transport maps for the users with smtp: but I can't get the mail to deliver?

Is there some setting somewhere where I can configure that there are extra email addresses that should still be accepted??

Here's my main.cf:

```
debug_peer_level = 9
debugger_command =
 PATH=/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin
 xxgdb $daemon_directory/$process_name $process_id & sleep 5
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
html_directory = no
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.3.3/samples
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.3.3/README_FILES
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
sender_bcc_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/bcc
mailbox_command = /usr/bin/procmail-wrapper -o -a $DOMAIN -d $LOGNAME
home_mailbox = Maildir/
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = permit_mynetworks permit_sasl_authenticated reject_unauth_destination
myhostname = <hostname>
mydomain = <domain>
smtpd_banner = Hello.  This server uses anti-spam and anti-virus functions.
relayhost = <relayserver>:<port>
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
#fallback_transport = smtp:<ip>:<port>
#fallback_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/fallback_map
luser_relay = dcmoody@<domain>
```

I've tried adding the email addresses to the virtual file pointing to themselves and that didn't work.

Please help!

Comment: Did you remember to `postmap /etc/postfix/transport`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Exchange, add a different namespace for email (like testdomain.local or somesuch), assign email addresses with that address to the users who need forwarding.  Set up forwarding in Postfix to forward usera@company.com to usera@testdomain.local (or .com or whatever - I don't know Postfix well enough to know if it'll accept non-publicly routable TLDs like Exchange will).  That'll fix the issue for the most part, though you'll need to make sure Exchange knows it's non-authoritative for the company.com domain.

Comment: Thank you for this solution.  I actually just tried something like this out on my own and that is what worked.